# Dictionary to datetime

Tags: python

I am looking to convert a string which is a date `'31-Dec-2018'` to datetime object: `datetime.date(2018, 12, 31)`. Is there any built in method that can be helpful ?

Say I have a dictionary `basedate` that has date in it. I have to convert it to datetime object. I am trying this:

```
basedate = {date: '31-Dec-2018'}
datetimetime.strptime(basedate, '%dd-%MMM-%yyyy')
```

I am getting an error while converting the string to datetime which states that it does not match the `%dd-%MM-%yyyy` format

Comment: The format codes are all single letters, so for example, `%dd` is parsed as "Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number" followed by a literal `d`.

Comment: BTW, `date` should be a string, `'date'`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the correct format: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?#strftime-strptime-behavior

And parse the actual string, not the dictionary.

```
datetime.strptime('31-Dec-2018','%d-%b-%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to your specific problem:

First correct your dictionary as:
basedate = {'date': '31-Dec-2018'}

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime

basedate = {'date': '31-Dec-2018'}
basedate = datetime.strptime(basedate['date'], '%d-%b-%Y').date()
```